# How to combine my jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 10 fields which will preview in live before submit

Example

```
$(function () {
    $(".word").keyup(function () {
        var word = $(this).val();
        $(".word_preview").html(word);
        return false;
    });
    $("#title").keyup(function () {
        var title = $(this).val();
        $(".title_preview").html(title);
        return false;
    });

   .......... more .............

    $("#desc").keyup(function () {
        var desc = $(this).val();
        $(".desc_preview").html(desc);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now I should write this code in 10 times. There have a way to combine this?

Comment: Could you show some of your html too? Is there a reason why you mix classes and ids?

Comment: @Andy take a look live demo. http://demos.9lessons.info/campaigndemo.html I used this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
$(".word, #desc, #title...").keyup(function () {
  var word = $(this).val();
  $("."+$(this).attr('id')+"_preview").html(word);
  return false;
});
```

**Edit**: As per Andrew's suggestion, there is actually no need to use the jQuery wrapper:

```
$(".word, #desc, #title...").keyup(function () {
  var word = this.value;
  $("."+this.id+"_preview").html(word);
  return false;
});
```

Thanks Andrew!

Comment: vargo: You could also just call `this.value` and `this.id` and avoid wrapping `this` in a jQuery object.